# Display a sting on android screen on a timer event

Tags: java, timer, textfield

I am writing n android app as part of my thesis and need to display/update/append data onto an android screen during a timer event - as follows:

(please excuse possible incorrect terminology and feel free to correct it)

I have a few classes in the app, however am trying to interact between "BlueActivity" and "BuzzActivity".

"BlueActivity" controls blue tooth. It turns on/off blue tooth,makes a connection and controls the socket.

"BuzzActivity" has a button "BUZZME": onClick, BuzzActivity passes (behind the sceens) into "BlueActivity" which sends a packet to the paired device (devDuino, who then radios out to a wearable device. the wearable device radios a reply of data readings back to devDuino). The paired device then replies this data back to "BlueActivity" which is read in through the socket listening on a timer. The data is in the format of a string and is called "retstr". The timer is started in "BlueActivity's" OnCreate() method.

I need to get "retstr" from "BlueActivity" into "BuzzActivity" and updating on the screen.

I have tried .setText and failed in the sense of App crashing. From research i hear about needing a handler to "dynamically" update the view?

Can some one please clarify this.

Code segments as follows:

BlueActivity:
    .........//stuff here
    //final String TAG = "On create";

```
    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            //Log.i(TAG, "In timer running");
            String retstr;
            retstr = mConnectThread.listen();  //Method to get my data from bluetooth packet
            //String text = String.valueOf(retstr); //failed attempts
            //BuzzActivity.DivingData.setText(text);
            Log.i(TAG, "retstr"); //Works like a charm to print out to log cat
            }
    }, 1000, 1000); 

    mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(mmDevice);
    mConnectThread.start();
}
```

BuzzActivity

```
.......//blueConnecter is called from the .xmlfile controling the buzz button "on click method"

public void blueConnecter(View view){
        DivingData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.DivingDataTextField);
        BlueActivity.visible(view); 
    }
```

Thanks for any help in advance.
Emma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a stack trace in the logcat output? You'll probably find that you are trying to update the UI thread from another thread. If that is the case, you need to update that view with runOnUiThread(). Here's an example:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 
            public void run() {
                DivingData.setText(newText);
            }
        });
```